# Problema con query

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el siguiente problema, quiero que la columna `Months` se deje de repetir, y la columna `Qty` se sume, pero la tabla es resultado de un query, dejo el query y la tabla de resultado como ejemplo:

```
select  DateName(month,date_estimated)as Months,count(date_estimated) as Qty 
from tbl_Crs
where Date_Estimated between (select  dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 
0)) and getdate() 
group by date_estimated
```

[image: Ejmplo de Resultado]

Comment: `group by DateName(month,date_estimated)` excelente, me sirvió, solamente que hora no se agrega en orden, creo que no es posible ordenarlo verdad?

Comment: Sí se puede, te lo indiqué en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agrupar por mes, no por fecha:

```
group by DateName(month,date_estimated)
```

Si lo quieres en orden de mes, modifica el `group by` de esta manera y agrégale el `order by` siguiente:

```
group by month(date_estimated), DateName(month,date_estimated)
order by month(date_estimated)
```

Comment: algún día seré como tu de experto... Gracias men.